# How to reference subclasses of static Java classes with generics in Scala

Tags: google-app-engine, scala, hadoop

I have this Java code:

```
public class TestMapper extends AppEngineMapper<Key, Entity, NullWritable, NullWritable> {
  public TestMapper() {
  }
// [... other overriden methods ...]
      @Override
      public void setup(Context context) {
        log.warning("Doing per-worker setup");
      }
}
```

...which I've converted to:

```
class TestMapper extends AppEngineMapper[Key, Entity, NullWritable, NullWritable] {
// [... other overriden methods ...]
      override def setup(context: Context) {
        log.warning("Doing per-worker setup")
      }
}
```

**Now the actual problem:**

***Context*** is defined as a nested class within the **org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper** class:

```
        public static class Mapper<KEYIN, VALUEIN, KEYOUT, VALUEOUT>   {
    //[... some other methods ...]
protected void setup(org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper<KEYIN,VALUEIN,KEYOUT,VALUEOUT>.Context context) throws java.io.IOException, java.lang.InterruptedException { /* compiled code */ }
        public class Context extends org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.MapContext<KEYIN,VALUEIN,KEYOUT,VALUEOUT> {

        public Context(org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration configuration, org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.TaskAttemptID conf, org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.RecordReader<KEYIN,VALUEIN> taskid, org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.RecordWriter<KEYOUT,VALUEOUT> reader, org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.OutputCommitter writer, org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.StatusReporter committer, org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.InputSplit reporter) throws java.io.IOException, java.lang.InterruptedException { /* compiled code */ }

        }
```

So I can't tell my Scala class where/what **Context** actually is. If **Mapper** had no generics I could reference **Context** via

```
Mapper#Context
```

but how can I tell that Mapper has Generics?

```
Mapper[_,_,_,_]#Context
```

...didn't work.

Comment: Thank you a lot for the question, I've spent several hours on exactly these classes!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to supply the exact base type for your type projection, in your case

```
Mapper[Key, Entity, NullWritable, NullWritable]#Context
```

so overriding `setup` would be written as

```
override def setup(context: Mapper[Key, Entity, NullWritable, NullWritable]#Context)
```

Usage can be simplified by introducing a type alias

```
class TestMapper extends AppEngineMapper[Key, Entity, NullWritable, NullWritable] {

  type Context = Mapper[Key, Entity, NullWritable, NullWritable]#Context

  override def setup(context: Context) = {
      // ...
   }
}
```

If you want to write multiple mappers you can refactor this into a trait that can be mixed into your implementation:

```
trait SMapper[A,B,C,D] extends Mapper[A,B,C,D] {
  type Context = Mapper[A,B,C,D]#Context
}

class TestMapper extends AppEngineMapper[Key, Entity, NullWritable, NullWritable]
                    with SMapper[Key, Entity, NullWritable, NullWritable] {
  override def setup(context: Context) = {
     // ...
  }
}
```

or for plain hadoop:

```
class TestMapper extends SMapper[Key, Entity, NullWritable, NullWritable] {
  override def setup(context: Context) = {
     // ...
  }
}
```

Comment: You don't actually need the existential type; since setup is a method of Mapper that is being overridden, you can just use Mapper[A,B,C,D]#Context (or a type alias) as you suggest at first.

Comment: I've added some info to my OP that may outline the problem better:
* Mapper is static (if it matters...)
* also I've added the class header

...your first solutions didn't work. I've got 

error: name clash between defined and inherited member:
method setup:(context: TestMapper1.this.Ctx)Unit and
method setup:(x$1: org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper[KEYIN,VALUEIN,KEYOUT,VALUEOUT]#Context)Unit in class AppEngineMapper
have same type after erasure: (context: org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper#Context)Unit
override def setup(context: Ctx) { 

I'm not sure how to apply the 3rd solution(same error)

Comment: Thank you for answer, but I wasn't able to make compile any of these solutions with the same error.

Comment: @DzmitryLazerka That answer was a bit messy because of all the edits. I restructured it - hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

The problems people have sometimes when using the accepted answer are due to a bug in Scala compiler ([link](https://groups.google.com/group/scala-user/browse_thread/thread/3a05e804dd0f48e3)).